# How to use Backbone javascript router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

I'm trying to learn [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/) so I created my first route:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home"
    }
});
var router = new Router();
router.on("route:home", function() {
    alert('the router works!!');
});
alert('after the router!!');
```

I then navigated my browser to `www.mydomain.com/thefolder/` which shows me the alert `after the router!!`, but unfortunately I don't get to see `the router works!!`. I tried inserting various routes, such as `"/"`, `"thefolder/"` and `"/thefolder/"`, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you can checkout this links  https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate and https://github.com/jcreamer898/RequireJS-Backbone-Starter - not bad starter kits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I may quote the doc for [`Backbone.Router`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

> During page load, after your application has finished creating all of
>   its routers, be sure to call `Backbone.history.start()`, or
>   `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` to route the initial URL.

Add `Backbone.history.start();` after your router declaration and you callback should be called.

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wTU58/ for a demo